# Copy Backup File [.tar.gz] File to USB Stick

Tags: raspbian

I created a backup file in Raspbian [on my Raspberry 2 Model B] which sits in the /home directory.  I want to copy it to my USB stick to the /media/pi directory.  The stick is formatted for EXT4. My Raspbian /root is also EXT4.

I tried using the File Manager to copy and paste but got a "Error opening file /mnt/pi/*filename*.tar.gz:Permission denied" message.  I also ran cp from the terminal window and got the message "cp cannot create regular file '/media/pi/filename.tar.gz' : Permission denied".  Here's that cp entry:

cp filename.tar.gz /media/pi

Clues would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you very much ...
Bill Cole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the owner and access rights with which your ext4 partition has been mounted. A quick solution may be to use `sudo cp filename.tar.gz /media/pi` to copy your archive file to your USB partition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.  Worked just fine.  Very kind of you to take the time to reply to my question.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your problem, then please accept this answet; click on the checkmark/tick.